# React.lazy returning 404 error when attempting to lazy load components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, code-splitting, react-lazy-load

I'm attempting to convert my React application to lazy load components dynamically to increase the Lighthouse performance score and have been following the [React Code Splitting Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) in order to do so.

Following the documentation, I attempted to switch how components were loaded in the App.js file as shown below:

```
//Before
import Component from './components/examples/Component';

//After
const Component = lazy(() => import('./components/examples/Component'));
```

However, when I do this the routes in App.js with *Component* fail to load as the site gets a 404 error when the server tries to grab http://localhost:3000/App.js . Do I need to add a route to my server to return each component I want to lazy load? There's nothing on the docs about this...

Looking for why this is happening, not a way to redo my App.js routes.

Comment: can you share you project structure and routes file

Comment: It looks like you are getting default 404 route which you may have defined in your routes try going to main route `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: If your are using webpack, have you defined the `output.publicPath` in the config?

Comment: Do you have wrapped your routes with `Suspense` it is necessary?
https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting

Comment: show your App.js content!

Comment: I second i-HmD's comment. Further, how are you serving your app. Are you serving app server-side? or client-side? As per React docs, `React.lazy and Suspense are not yet available for server-side rendering. If you want to do code-splitting in a server rendered app, we recommend Loadable Components. It has a nice guide for bundle splitting with server-side rendering.`